# Alternative to Contains method in Generics

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I use C# Asp.net 4 and Linq.

I have a Generics of type BOOL.
I need to check if at least an element in the Generics is TRUE.
At the moment I'm using the `Contains` method (all is working fine).

```
List<bool> userIsValid = new List<bool>();
userIsValid.Add(false);
userIsValid.Add(true);
userIsValid.Add(false);
if (userIsValid.Contains(true))
// do smt here
```

I would like to know if exist another approach without using the `Contains` method.

Many Thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with the `Contains` approach?  It works for this sample

Comment: Why would you not use `Contains`, when it does exactly what you want?

Comment: There is alternatives, but why? They wouldn't be any more concise than this.

Comment: Mr. Disappointment could you please post your alternative? Many thanks

Comment: Avoid using Contains

In LINQ, we use contains method for checking existence. It is converted to "WHERE IN" in SQL which cause performance degrades.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Any():](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx)

```
if(userIsValid.Any(b => b)) { ... }
```

This will return true as soon as it hits a true condition specified by the lambda. In this case as the values in your list are booleans it simply needs to check the value. A more verbose way of writing it would be `.Any(b => b == true)` but this is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

These would work:

[Exists()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca.aspx)

```
  userIsValid.Exists(true);
```

or

[Any()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx)

```
userIsValid.Any(x => x);
```

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do this:

```
if (userIsValid.Aggregate((x,y) => x || y)) { ... }
```

I wouldn't do this because it is not very clear code, and it is actually slower than the other options because it won't return as soon as it finds a true.

But if you are just looking for esoteric solutions...

Comment: Thanks Marting for your comment